# Paging and selecting rows starting with a letter from a DB

Tags: sql, select

I have a table where each row is a username with associated vote count

The goal is to do paging by username

so you can click on the letter C and get to the C's

But if there are only like 2 C's, then you wanna show 18 D's as well
or 12 D's and 6 E's

So how do i find where to start
the query like, select from whatever limit XX, 20
how do i find that XX where the C's start, F's start, etc

Basically treat the first letter as a number and select the top 20.

Comment: As you can see from the answers, syntax depends on which DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

select * from table
where name >= 'C'
order by name
limit 20

Comment: Well, that's almost so easy I'm embarassed

Comment: I think this is way wrong. What about the next page if there are 40 Cs?

Comment: @DVK: you'd save the last one from the previous page and change the > value.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM [Table] WHERE [username] >= 'C' ORDER BY [username]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always select the top 20.

```
SELECT Top 20 * FROM Users WHERE Username >= 'C' ORDER BY Username
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way (assuming the pages go to web server and page #N is requested from web server) :

```
select bottom 20 from 
 ( select top N*20 *
 from   myTable
 order by username
 ) TOPNPAGES
```